# How to overlap two controls

Tags: c#, .net, controls, gdi+

I have a Circle and a Line control.
Circle control's OnPaint draws a circle and Line control's one draws a line. These two controls are contained in another control (DrawingControl).
I need to put a Line over a Circle, but Circle's background deletes the Line. I tried enabling transparency and overriding Circle's OnPaintBackground method, but it doesn't seem to work.
Do you have any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does [this tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Nildo%20Soares%20de%20Araujo/TransparentControls11152005074108AM/TransparentControls.aspx) help? It consists of **three** steps: Enabling transparency, overriding OnPaintBackground and overriding OnMove

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282838/drawing-on-top-of-controls-inside-a-panel-c-winforms#316526) about creating a diagonal-line control.  This technique does not require using transparency, but instead uses an irregularly-shaped region.  Creating a circle control this way would be a little more complicated than the line example, since you'll need to use bezier curves instead of line segments in order to create a smooth circle.