# OnPaint clearing background on invalidate

Tags: c#, winforms, onpaint

I'm developing an application in which I have a parent UserControl that draws to the screen during OnPaint with several child UserControls doing the same.  However, when the parent or child are invalidated, The parent control's painting is overwritten with the background color.

[image: Illustration]

How do I allow the back control's painting to show through, rather than having this control-colored square?

Comment: See [How can I create a transparent System.Windows.Forms.Panel on top of two other already existing Panels then draw a line on my transparent panel?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4973980/719186)

Comment: It probably has the wrong Parent.  The form instead of the usercontrol that is underneath it.  So you see the form as the background.  Same basic approach as https://stackoverflow.com/a/9387562/17034