# How can I generate a 'flow' arrow from one control to another in a windows form application?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, visual-studio

I have a windows forms application where the user can generate a bunch of user controls that get displayed in a panel.  These controls can be dragged around by the user.  That is going great.  Now I want the user to be able to link the controls together somehow.  Ideally it would be an arrow that goes from one control to another (like in this image: http://www.cocoontech.com/w/images/8/82/Premise_ObjectDiagram.png), but I am willing to try other things.  I would love to find some kind of tutorial on doing something like this.

Answer (score 0):

if all controls are inside a panel then override the panel's Paint event and draw the arrows

[This discussion might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282838/drawing-on-top-of-controls-inside-a-panel-c-winforms) - MusiGenesis's answer seems close to what you want