# draw line on a component

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a table with 2 columns, in one of these columns I have a component created by me. I would like to draw a line in this table bring to front, but when I try with the code I post, the line goes behind the other component I created

```
 public void CoTableLayoutPanel2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 0, 50, this.Width, 1);

    }
```

Comment: You need a transparent panel on top of your component that you can then draw your line on. When you draw on the panel that hosts the component, the drawing goes underneath any child controls of the panel (as you've discovered).

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: With enough care you can also try to draw patched on both the parent and those controls you want the line to cross. This is simple for some controls like Labels but less so for others..

Comment: @500 Did you try that? Transparency wil only work with nested controls, but the panel will not be nested in the controls inside the component..

Comment: @Mrpit: What types of controls are in the component and how deep are they nested?

Comment: @TaW 
I have a table divided into 2 columns, only one component above which recalls the other components inside

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of **composing** the graphics by letting **all nested controls draw their part of the graphics** onto themselves.

The trick is to make them all participate and shift the `Graphics` to make the composite seamless.

Note that not all controls support the `Paint` event properly; most notably the legacy `TextBox` will not play along..

To make it work I create a class to store the graphics data; it is quite simplistic. For more involved stuff one can simply expand it..:

```
public class DrawAction
{
    public Point p1 { get; set; }
    public Point p2 { get; set; }
    public Color c1 { get; set; }
    public int mode { get; set; }

    public DrawAction(Point p1_, Point p2_, Color c_, int mode_)
    {
        p1 = p1_; p2 = p2_; c1 = c_; mode = mode_;
    }

    public void Draw(Graphics g)
    {
        switch (mode)
        {
            case 0: // line
                using (Pen pen = new Pen(c1)) 
                  g.DrawLine(pen, p1, p2);
                break;
            case 1: // rectangle
                using (Pen pen = new Pen(c1)) 
                  g.DrawRectangle(pen, p1.X, p1.Y, p2.X - p1.X, p2.Y - p1.Y);
                break;
            case 2: // filled rectangle
                using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(c1)) 
                  g.FillRectangle(brush, p1.X, p1.Y, p2.X - p1.X, p2.Y - p1.Y);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I won't show code for the `UserObject`. It contains a few controls including a `GroupBox` with a `Radiobutton` in it to show that deeply nested controls still work.

The class has a `Draw` method which one can call, passing in a valid `Graphics` object.

To initialize we use this code:

```
void initPainting(Control parent, Control baseCtl)
{
    foreach (Control ctl in parent.Controls)
    {
        ctl.Paint += (s, e) =>
        {
            foreach (var drawing in drawings)
            {
                Point offset = 
                     baseCtl.PointToClient(ctl.PointToScreen(Point.Empty));

                Graphics g = e.Graphics;
                g.TranslateTransform(-offset.X, -offset.Y);
                drawing.Draw(g);
                g.ResetTransform();

            }
        };
        initPainting(ctl, baseCtl);  // recursion
    }
}
```

I use a lambda to hook up the `Paint` events to all controls.

The method is **recursive** to catch all controls inside a common parent control.

Here is the list of graphics..

```
 List<DrawAction> drawings = new List<DrawAction>();
```

and the initialization for it:

```
    ..
    InitializeComponent();
    Size sz = tableLayoutPanel1.Size;
    drawings.Add(
      new DrawAction(Point.Empty, new Point(sz.Width, sz.Height), Color.Red, 0));
    drawings.Add(
      new DrawAction(new Point(0, sz.Height), new Point(sz.Width, 0), Color.Blue, 0));
    drawings.Add(
      new DrawAction(new Point(50, 50), new Point(300, 300), Color.Green, 1));

    initPainting(tableLayoutPanel1, tableLayoutPanel1);
```

This is the result and the designer view:

[image][image]

You can see that the `TextBoxes` don't play along; also that there is a tiny glitch with the `GroupBoxes`, not sure why..