# How can I make for every single point special colors and sizes? (Graphics, Paint and so on)

Tags: c#, winforms

My problem is: I want to set special colors and sizes for a point if a if{} is true. Please watch the code and read more down below to understand.

So, in the if{} down below pbxkarte_Paint there will be set other colors if one of the if is true. The point is that the different colored points get the color of the true if{} case = For example "reh" in the if{} is true its brushes color is brown, I do set a brown point - but when the "wilds" is true "wilds" brushes color is black, all points get black although there is the "reh" point which should be brown!

```
List<Point> dots = new List<Point>();
int dotSize = 12;

Rectangle fromPoint(Point pt, int size)
{
    return new Rectangle(pt.X - size/ 2, pt.Y - size / 2, size, size);
}
private void Pbxkarte_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (!dots.Contains(e.Location))
    {
        dots.Add(e.Location);
        Pbxkarte.Invalidate();  // show the dots
    }
}
private void Pbxkarte_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    bool hit = false;
    foreach (var dot in dots)
    {
        using (GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath())
        {
            gp.AddEllipse(fromPoint(dot, dotSize));
            if (gp.IsVisible(e.Location))
            {
                hit = true; break;
            }
        }
    }
    Cursor = hit ? Cursors.Hand : Cursors.Default;
}
private void Pbxkarte_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var dot in dots)
    {
        using (GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath())
        {
            //gp.AddEllipse(fromPoint(dot, dotSize));
            //e.Graphics.FillPath(Brushes.Red, gp);
            if (listboxlbx.SelectedItem == reh)
            {
                dotSize = 10;
                gp.AddEllipse(fromPoint(dot, dotSize));
                e.Graphics.FillPath(Brushes.Brown, gp);
            }
            else if (listboxlbx.SelectedItem == wilds)
            {
                dotSize = 10;
                gp.AddEllipse(fromPoint(dot, dotSize));
                e.Graphics.FillPath(Brushes.Black, gp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So far all points look the same, right? Your `if` clause only test a listbox and makes no difference for the separate points. If it shall do, what is the criterion?

Comment: Can you give more details about "reh" and "wilds"?

Comment: @AbdelAzizAbdelLatef "reh" and "wilds" are both Objects that I created, they are also placed in a List<>.

Comment: @TaW Yes, every point looks the same as the other. How can I make special attributes (like colors, styles and so on) for every single point?

Comment: For this you should create a class. This is oop and very extensible. And not hard at all! See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57397327/draw-line-on-a-component/57415540#57415540) for an example class that can serve as a template to start from. You would create a List<yourClass> instead of the list<point> and add a new element to it upon each click. You can add alltribute like size etc to the class and set or change it whenever you want.. - You still will need to decide just how the user will select the attibute like color size, maybe shape etc..

Comment: Note how the class knows how to draw itself. You can also add a methode `bool Contains(Point)` that checks if a point is on a dot.. - You could write a faster solution like this: Add two more lists of color and int and set them like you now set the points. But using a class is highly recommended as it not only ties data together that belong together and keeps them always in synch; it also lets you add methods (knowledge) and makes it so much easier to let the application grow...

Comment: Try to use listboxlbx.SelectedIndex instead of listboxlbx.SelectedItem. This may give you a clue about the source of the problem.